# How to use socket.on in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am building a small chat app, but I have problems with receiving messages in react. The problem is that when I receive a message I `setMessages`, but at the same time the `messages` state gets cleared. The problem is problably that I don't know where to place `socket.on`, currently it's inside a `useEffect` hook.

```
export const Room = ({ socket }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const { id } = useParams();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("join room", id);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages([
        ...messages,
        { message: message, createdBy: "other", id: uuidv4() },
      ]);
    });
  }, []);
  const sendMessage = () => {
    console.log("send");
    socket.emit("message", input);
    setMessages([
      ...messages,
      { message: input, createdBy: "me", id: uuidv4() },
    ]);
  };
  console.log("foo");
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center text-center">
      <div className="w-screen h-screen px-2 max-w-4xl mt-10">
        <p className="text-3xl">Code: {id}</p>
        <div className="bg-white w-full h-3/4 rounded-xl border-2 border-black overflow-y-auto">
          {messages.map((message) => (
            <Message
              text={message.message}
              createdBy={message.createdBy}
              key={message.id}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-row border-2 border-black mt-2 rounded-xl p-2 bg-white">
          <input
            className="flex-grow border-none focus:outline-none"
            onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            className=" bg-green-500 rounded-xl px-2 py-1"
            onClick={sendMessage}
          >
            Send
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have a closure problem. `messages` is not what you think it is when it is run inside the useEffect -- it may not be the latest version.

It's safer and good practice to use the functional variant of the setter. This way you can be certain that `messages` is the current version:

```js
setMessages(messages => [
  ...messages,
  { message: message, createdBy: "other", id: uuidv4() },
]);
```